# Android Html string with custom font shows different bold effect from iOS

Tags: android

Feature:  I have an html string with  tags (added to specific parts of the text) coming from backend to be parsed in Android and iOS.

Current behavior: I can show the text in a TextView with the bolds but they look different
Android:

[image]

iOS:

[image]

Expected behavior: Android bold string should look the same as in iOS

More info:

- The font i am using is a custom font: Montserrat in otf format, more objectively Montserrat-Light
  both with same font size
- The font is stored in project assets and its used by setting typeface on textview
- Tried with a Webview and the result was the same
- Tried to set a different font for the bold using:

```
font = "assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.otf"
<font face='$font'>string to bold</font>
```

- To parse html string into text im using

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(htmlText, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

- Html string example i am using:

```
<p><strong>WHAT DO YOU NEED?</strong></p>
```

My goal is to find a way of making  effect look the same in Android as it looks in iOS

Comment: First, all the reference images. Also `Android bold string should look the same as in iOS` why you think it should?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I dont think it should, i want to find a way if there is one, of achieving that result. Its a requirement for the project.

Comment: As I mentioned - please post expectations vs current state. Also these are two separate platforms. I'd not waste too much time on making these two the same. In fact all the "write once deploy everywhere" frameworks failed because i.e. android uses hate when app is not feeling native (but i.e. iOS).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i agree with everything you just said.
The Current behavior and Expected behavior is on the description, i can´t post image examples because i dont have enough reputation to put images.
Is there any way i can make it more clear?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i was able to add links on what is happening

Comment: `i can´t post image examples because i dont have enough reputation` - true, yet you can attach images and I (or anyone else with higher rank) can turn it into embedded images

Comment: Judging by the images you attached, the look is different because the font rendering differ. I'd personally spend no time on this further. You set your font, you set you want boldface. It should be rendered as you requested. It is as you like (your font boldfaced)? Good. Differs visually from other platforms? Well, maybe/perhaps/yes - but that's how it is on this platform. And this is where your journey ends (IMHO) as OS knows better (you like it or not).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I guess that is really the way to go here. Thank you for your help :)